# If fully colorblind people only see shades of white,gray, and black, does that mean that the colors black, white, gray are colors humans can’t see?

Tags: human-biology, brain

And since the brain can be tricked to thinking that objects with mostly black and grey gradients are moving, like optical illusions, does that mean motion has a color?

Comment: According to your title you should consider a repetition from optics.  But anyway it is quite interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question: if fully color-blind people see whites, blacks, and greys, that means that humans can see them colors. After all, aren't color-blind people humans?

If you actually think about it, is color just created by evolved cells? If so, should we not see just black, grey, and white?